# NSWindowController allocation and initialization crashing unexpectedly

Tags: c++, objective-c, nswindow, objective-c++, nswindowcontroller

I'm currently building a C++ plugin for some software, which, when the relevant function is called, displays a nib which I built in XCode. Up until today everything has been working fine, displaying and working with the nib / Objective-C++ / C++ has caused no problems.

However out of the blue everything started crashing at the call to show the preferences dialog. I've narrowed the crashing code down to this line:

```
PreferencesWindowController *prefsWindowController = [[PreferencesWindowController alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"PreferencesWindow"];
```

PreferencesWindowController is a superclass of NSWindowController, and PreferencesWindow is a .xib file which superclasses NSWindow also.

Does anyone have any idea why this is crashing?

Comment: What is the code for the initializer of `PreferencesWindowController`?  Is the File's Owner set correctly in the XIB to be a class of that type, connected to a window?  (Also, "superclass" is the wrong term in your description...NSWindowController is the superclass of PreferencesWindowController.)

Comment: Yeah you're right sorry, didn't say that correctly! I haven't overridden the default initializer code so it should just be initializing as normal. Also, the File's Owner is set to PreferencesWindowController and the XIB class is PreferencesWindow.. However, I loaded a revision which I found in my dropbox from last week which was had no errors, but this still crashed, so I think there is some corruption in my Xcode or SDK or something.. Reinstalling Xcode as we speak.

Comment: Just to nitpick, I think you have the terminology wrong... If `PreferencesWindowController` is a superclass of `NSWindowController`, it means that `NSWindowController` inherits from `PreferencesWindowController`. It's probably the other way around, with `PreferencesWindowController` being a _subclass_.

Comment: Yep I got that from Kevin, honest mistake.

Comment: It may help to describe some of the bindings.  Also note that XIB is a textual (XML) format so you can run a raw `diff` command on the working file and the broken file to see what's different.  (This may offer clues, e.g. some property that isn't there anymore.)

Comment: There are no working files, that's the issue. I loaded up the revision but it crashes as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I was developing a Plug-in for some software, which apparently loaded plug-ins from two different directories on a Mac. I had the plug-in in both directories and for some reason having it being loaded in twice obviously messed around with the memory somehow. Anyway I deleted it from one of the plug-in directories and now it works fine.